# Exclude serializer field and set value as request.user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I exclude `user` field and set value of this field as request.user?(in `create()`)

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        #exclude = ['user']
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the user from the serializer (set it as read only) and override the `ViewSet`'s`perform_create`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

the `user` will be added to the serializer's validated_data which will be maped to the user field from your model.

Edit:
I just realized that you may want the user field to be read-only which should be fine as well